# Can けれども be analysed further?

Tags: grammar, particles, etymology, conjugations, conjunctions

Consider the conjunction ども, e.g.:

- 行けども
- 言えども

Formation rule:

- Verb Hypothetical form (仮定形) + ども

This leads me to hypothesise that the conjunction けれども (meaning "but; however; although") is built from けれ + ども.

I am unable to find a verb that is けれる. There is 蹴る though.

What is the composition of けれども? Or is it impossible to break it down further?

Comment: There is also the proverb 働けども、働けども、我が暮らし楽に成らず

Comment: @user1205935: That is not a proverb.  I think that you are talking about a poem ([tanka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanka_%28poetry%29)) by [石川啄木](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takuboku_Ishikawa): はたらけど はたらけど[猶]{なほ}わが[生活]{くらし}楽にならざり ぢっと手を見る.

Answer (score 6):

As you have already discovered, -domo attaches to the hypothetical form (仮定形). Historically, this was known as realis (已然形). The kere here is the hypothetical / realis form of -keri. -keri is an obsolete suffix (助動詞) which expresses hearsay recollection.

-keri itself may be further split apart as a contraction of -ki ari, where -ki is another obsolete recollectional suffix and ari is the verb ar-i "to be".

While simple and imprecise, you may think of -keri as past tense. You may still find remnants of it in expressions such as "dakke".

Comment: Actually, [Daijirin](http://www.excite.co.jp/dictionary/japanese/?search=%E3%81%91%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A9%E3%82%82&match=beginswith&itemid=DJR_keredomo_-020) says the けれ element from conjugation of adjectives, not the auxiliary verb けり.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for the report. However, I said nothing about Daijirin, which I agree with. Though that keredomo is a different word than the -keredomo that I was describing. See for example 竹取物語: 「かぐや姫を見まほしうして、物も食はず思ひつゝ、かの家に行きてたたずみありき_けれども_、かひあるべくもあらず」 http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~Taiju/taketori.htm I suppose the question should define what けれども they intend.

Comment: Off topic: “The kere here is…”: I first read this as /kɪər hɪər/ and wondered what “kere” means, then I realized my mistake.  I wonder if anyone read it as けれへれ.

Comment: @Dono. "Though that keredomo is a different word than the -keredomo that I was describing". There are two different keredomo ?

Comment: @Flaw Yes, with different meanings and different etymologies. One I described above and gave an example, the other Zhen links to Daijirin. Please clarify what けれども you would like an answer to.

Comment: I did not know there were two separate keredomo. I am only aware of the conjunction けれども that is used to connect a disjunctive/concessive clause and that it may be shortened to けれど、けども、けど

Comment: @Flaw: In that case, then you'll want the link in the first comment.

Comment: @ZhenLin Would you like make your first comment into an answer? Since it directly addresses the question.